# get rewritten url from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting

We're using IIS 7 "URL Rewrite" feature for some of our urls

for example a rule that rewrites

```
/viewSompage.aspx?id=123&title=some-title
```

rewrites to

```
/View/SomePage/some-title/123/
```

For several purposes (one of them being able to set the rewritten url in an e-mail template etc) we need to get the rewritten url in codebehind, given the string.

I know the rewritter automatically applies those in pages using the outbound rules, but i still need to get the rewritten url for other purposes.

i'd like to be able to pass a url string, and make the urlrewiter apply any applicable rules to the given url example

```
String rewrittenURL = ApplyRewritingRules("/viewSompage.aspx?id=123&title=some-title");
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok i found a decent solution that doesn't require me to do redundant stuff.

```
Page.ResolveUrl(Request.RawUrl)
```

Where Page is an instance of System.Web.UI.Page ... that's your standard aspx page

Request ... if you're trying to access the request, use HttpContect.Current.Request ...

```
RawUrl = /viewSompage.aspx?id=123&title=some-title
```

rewrites to (according to my rules specified in the web.config)

```
/View/SomePage/some-title/123/
```

from there i can build the entire link like this with just one line of code:

```
String url = String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, Page.ResolveUrl(request.RawUrl));
```

Comment: You have it the wrong way round - `/View/SomePage/some-title/123/` is rewritten to `/viewSompage.aspx?id=123&title=some-title`

Answer (score 0):

you could create a custom url rewriter class and store its configuration in a sql table

Table Url_Rules:

- int id
- nvarchar(250) original
- nvarchar(250) rewritten

you can use this table to store multiple rules, then use global.asax to perform the rewrite rule by looking in the db for the appropriate path e.g:

SELECT original from Url_Rules where rewritten =`'http://someurl/article/id'`

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    urlEngine.Rewrite(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.ToString)
End Sub
```

urlEngine.Rewrite does the job to get the data from db then it apply it to the current context:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(url_from_db)
```

this way you can uninstall IIS 7 URL Rewrite, than you can make a second method that returns just the url encoded as string and email it:

```
public Function GetUrl(ByVal url As String)
       return url_from_db
End Function
```

Comment: a) i don't want to do an extra db store or create a separate class for that. We've defined the rules in the web.config based on regular expressions. It just makes the whole thing redundant and the extra db calls can also affect performance.

Comment: ok than is even easier, just use the data from the web.config, get the rule and run it against your url with Regex.Replace() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx

Comment: there has to be a more elegant solution. Was hoping for something that would tell the underwriter to parse a given url and return what it's actual output would be.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't much of an answer, but I don't think you should be using the Url Rewrite for that purpose.  It makes your code hard to read because things are happening server-side that are invisible to your code and I'm not entirely sure that you can even change it dynamically.  If I remember correctly, that stuff is in the web.config and changing values in it requires a recompile by IIS.